# Net use for shared folder process doesn't work in C# suddenly

Tags: c#, shared

I think my problem is easy, but after days of research and test unable to find solution.

I have the following method that connects to a specific shared folder from IP and then opens the folder under "explorer"

To do this I used Net use command. And initially it works perfect!

But after adding more commands to my application. The net use not working. I tried to create it from 0, and still the same.

If I create a new one and only add few features the method works perfectly, but If I surpass a "limit" of features the method not working.

I'm totally lost why and doesn't understand the same code works in the app at the beginning and doesn't work If I add more things.

I tried to wait for the task, different Threads, creating it in other method...  same results.

```
    private static void LaunchFiles(string computer1, string Route1, string serial1, string program1)
    {
            ipcalc calcula = new ipcalc(); //Customed class that calculates the IP
      
            int numero1IP = calcula.ipnum1(int.Parse(serial1)); //Calculates the second number and third number of the IP
            double numero2IP = calcula.ipnum2(double.Parse(serial1));


//First I launch net use
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new 
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("net.exe", @"use \\10." + numero1IP + "." + numero2IP + "." + computer1 + @"\c password /USER:user");
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            System.Diagnostics.Process processTemp = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            processTemp.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            processTemp.Start();

//Second I open the folder with explorer.
            Thread.Sleep(1000); //I tried different values here, same result
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(program1, @" \\10." + numero1IP + "." + numero2IP + "." + computer1 + Route1);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you'd better remove try catch while debugging, or at least log exception message.

Comment: You should capture the output from net use and print it out so you can see if it's kicking out any errors. Perhaps it's saying "multiple connections to the same resource using different user names are not allowed"

Comment: @CaiusJard I did this:

            string output = processTemp.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();


            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            MessageBox.Show(output);

Returns "The command completed succesfuly".

Still in same situation.

Comment: do you want to use `net use` command to create mapped share drive?

Comment: Not really, I don't want create a Drive like z: just make the fólder accesible to open It like another local folder @Lei Yang

Comment: What does "Not Working" mean?  What's the exception message/stack?

Comment: Is the code above an example of working or non-working code?  And on what line does it fail?

Comment: @RBarryYoung The shared folder is not accessible. It doesn't return any error. As mentioned before, the command is completed succesfuly. When the next command "explorer" is started the folderis not available. If the command is executed in prompt the folder becomes accessible.

Comment: OK, so is the code above a working example?  If so, then can you give an example of the additional lines that result in it being non-working?

Comment: It's simple method, it can't run by itself. I can't attach the whole program, it's too large. Did you read my first text? The code is working until I add more features to the program. No is not returned. The command shows "succesfully" but shared folder is not accessible under explorer. @RBarryYoung

Comment: I don't know what "add more features" means. I need to see an example of it.